# Does IndexedDb have the equivalent of a transaction.completing event?

Tags: indexeddb

Is there any way to know when all requests have finished but before the transaction commits?  The `transaction.oncomplete` event does not allow for any additional logic to run while still calling `transaction.abort()`.  So, a better way is to use the equivalent of `transaction.completing` (I made this up) which will only fire after all requests were complete but still allow for `transaction.abort()` to be called.

http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/

In general, this should be considered good practice.  In the most common case simple syntax errors would not leave the database in a inconsistent case.

Comment: *"The transaction.oncomplete event does not allow for any additional logic to run while still calling transaction.abort()."* Couldn't understand this part, elaborate please?

Comment: Once you know all your stores have updated (no unique constraint errors, etc) you could perform operations related to that large data set: update the ram cache or run more data constraint checking.  If there are any errors there it is good to report the error and rollback everything so the operation can begin again from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to know when all requests have finished but before the transaction commits?

Yes but you have to write code that listens to all your operations' `success` or `error` events. There is no `beforecommit` event as you would like. But feel free to make a case for its inclusion on [public-webapps](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps).

> In the most common case simple syntax errors would not leave the database in a inconsistent case.

How can the database get into an inconsistent state? That's why the `error` event exists and by default causes the transaction to abort. See http://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dfn-fire-an-error-event.